# How to create wizard screen layout using struts2?

Tags: struts2

I want to build a wizard screens for my project. For that i am using struts2 framework. Can anyone help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to implement the [ScopeInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ScopeInterceptor.html) to create wizard like interfaces.  An alternative is to implement custom conversational scope.  A great tutorial on this can be found [here](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/using_a_conversation_scope).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is... don't. At least not directly. Use Spring Webflow. It is vastly superior at wizard and conversational state style processes.  **Note:** Spring Webflow can be used on top of other Web frameworks, most notably Spring MVC and JSF. There is a [Struts 2 Webflow plug-in](http://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/spring-webflow-plugin.html).

If you're not going to use Webflow, it's not really much different to coding normal controllers/actions/views/forms, except the logic can get really tedious.